# Spark: Query for multiple conditions at the same time

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So `Dataframe.where` can be used to filter a dataframe for the rows given by an expression, like this:

```
df.where(($"group_id" == 1234) || ($"group_id" == 4434))
```

or to give a more complex example

```
df.where(($"group_id" == 1234 && $"country" === "PL") || ($"group_id" == 4434 $"country" === "FR"))
```

I am interest in whether I can supply these conditions somehow as a list, so suppose I have a list of `group_id`'s, `List((1234, "PL"), (4434, "FR"), ....)` then I would like to efficiently filter the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
val df = Seq((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")).toDF()
df.show()
```

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+
```

```
val list = List((1,"a"),(3,"c"))
val cols = List("_1","_2")

def mkCol(values: List[(Any,Any)], columns: List[String]) = list.map(s=>col(columns.apply(0)) === s._1 && col(columns.apply(1)) === s._2)
                                                                .reduce((a,b)=>a.or(b))

val col = mkCol(list,cols)
col.explain(true)
```

```
((('_1 = 1) && ('_2 = a)) || (('_1 = 3) && ('_2 = c)))
```

```
df.where(col).show()
```

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+
```